# Unexpected behavior when loading SnowFlake data from Databricks environment

Tags: scala, apache-spark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, databricks

I am just trying to load data from a **Snowflake** table as below (with **Spark/Scala** in Databricks env) :

```
def loadDataFromSnowFlake(SfOptions: Map[String, String], query: String): DataFrame =
    spark.read
        .format("net.snowflake.spark.snowflake")
        .options(SfOptions)
        .option("query", query)
        .load()
    }

val SfOptions = ???
val query  = "SELECT * FROM databaseName.public.tableName LIMIT 10"
val testDf = loadDataFromSnowFlake(SfOptions, query)
    
testDf.show()
testDf.show()
```

The thing is that the two show() at the end of my script sent me back two different results, and I do not understand how it is possible when my dataframe **testDf** is declared as immutable.

I would appreciate a clarification on that.
Thanks a lot.
Cheers

Comment: `show()` does nothing more than triggering an action which will send the query to the Snowflake database. Without any ordering there is no guarantee that `limit 10` will return the same 10 result

Answer (score 0):

<strike>show() doesn't guarantee that same output would be returned. It just prints 20 rows. If you call show another time, you may get differnt output.</strike>

I run few test cases, and found that even running `show()` on same dataframe print same output.

Comment: Hello Jai Ranjan Kumar, thanks for your reply. I have brought only 10 lines from my table so I didn't expect different outputs. Once the testDf is fed with those 10 lines and declared as "val", I didn't get how the testDf value could be different.

Answer (score 0):

Lets try to order data on the Snowflake side:

```sql
SELECT      * 
FROM        databaseName.public.tableName 
ORDER BY    <column_name> 
LIMIT       10
```

It could be a problem. As an alternative, you could use the `display(testDf)` function. It is supported with Python, but I'm not sure about Scala.